# Using overflow hidden to hide floated elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my project I have multiple buttons that are floated, on a default state I want to hide the buttons not using `.hide()` or `display:none` because I want to scroll them out.

Here is a fiddle that explains everything [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDnPa/1/)

It's setup well in my mind (open to other suggestions though), I came to the conclusion the best way to expand the buttons would not be to hide them but set the wrapper to 0% with `overflow:hidden` then when I want to display them I just expand the wrapper, this is fine with one element/object, but when multiple element/objects are floated then it breaks. Id like to know why its doing that and a solution would be wonderful.

Again here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDnPa/1/)

Just some code in case you don't want to see the wonderful fiddle I made.

**The CSS:**

```
.container {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 25px 0;
    transition: 2s all ease;
}
.zero-width {
    width: 0%
}
.stationary-object {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    color: #777; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- It works with one object, not with two -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="stationary-object">I shouldnt move</div>
</div>

<!-- With objects floated it breaks, how do I get the floated objects to stay -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="stationary-object button">Button</div>
    <div class="stationary-object">I shouldnt move</div>
</div>

<button>Toggle Width</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).prevAll().toggleClass('zero-width')
})
```

The code is straight out of the fiddle, and it's just a representation of how to hide floated elements with 0% and `overflow: hidden` by no means is this live code. When I can figure out how to keep the floated elements from dropping, then I can apply that to a more functional piece.

Thanks

Comment: If you change the width to `0` the children nodes will not have space to float in. It's simple as it sounds. The drop is caused by the space reduction and also can be avoided with a fixed height and `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to your .container class

And replace float:left with `display: inline-block;` in your .stationary-object class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDnPa/7/)**

```
.container {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 25px 0;
    transition: 2s all ease;
    white-space: nowrap; /* <-- */
}

.stationary-object {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block; /* <-- */
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    color: #777; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah this seems more professional I would say, but can you explain the difference and why it is better? I can see inline-block being better than floating.

Comment: Well for starters, you don't need to add extra wrappers to your markup. Neither are you limited to a fixed width

Comment: Oh I see that, I didnt realize this didnt add the wrapper lol ok nice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an inner `<div>` with a very large width, and that will hold the stationary-object buttons in a single line without wrapping.  http://jsfiddle.net/ZDnPa/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="stationary-object button">Button</div>
        <div class="stationary-object">I shouldnt move</div>
    </div>
</div>

.inner {width:10000px;}
```

Comment: Nice, cant believe I didnt think to add another wrapper... wonderful :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the stationery objects in a div that has a fixed width. See this example - http://jsfiddle.net/taneleero/ZDnPa/5/

```
.hold-the-width {
    width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the elements inside a div, and set that divs width to a fixed value

```
<div class="container">
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="stationary-object button">Button</div>
    <div class="stationary-object">I shouldnt move</div>
</div>
```

```
.fixed{width:450px;}
```

Updated Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDnPa/8/